# Ruby print out a float with optional digits

Tags: ruby, floating-accuracy

I'm trying to print out a float number, that has the value `5`

What I get when it print it out is `5.0`, so my question is:

How to i make it so, that if the value is just `5`, it will just print `5` without the `.0` after it, and if it is `5.2` or so, it will print out that?

I've looked around, but all I found was to either force it one way or another.

Can someone help me in the right direction? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
number.to_s.gsub(/\.?0*$/, '')
```

This will even work for `number = "5.30" # => '5.3'`.

Comment: Nice, haven't though about using regex for the matter.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of dirty solutions.

1.

```
a = 5.0
puts a.ceil == a ? a.ceil : a
```

2.

```
5.1.to_s.chomp ".0" #=> 5.1
5.0.to_s.chomp ".0" #=> 5
```

Comment: Nice readable solution. I needed to modify it just a little bit for getting it to work:

a.ceil == a ? a.ceil.to_i : a

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this? `5` and `5.000` conveys different messages, because they have different numbers of [significant figures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures). The first indicates "five give or minus a half" whereas the latter indicates "five to the nearest thousandth".

Comment: Why should the first indicate "five give or minus a half"? Lack of decimal digits doesn't have to imply rounding of any kind.

Comment: @Mladen: Can you expand further?

Comment: the reason is because the user can give a estimate of 5 hours,  but also 3.5 hours. To keep the view clean, I don't want to write 5.0 as the .0 is just clutter for the user

Comment: Exactly. Users don't always approach numbers mathematically. In some cases, `5`, `5.0` and `5.000` are equivalents, only of different readability. BTW, why `5` couldn't mean _exactly_ five, and not _five plus or minus half_?

Comment: @Mladen: If it was exactly five, then it'd be an integer, not a float.